Which version of Redis supports Python 3.1 or higher
Currently we are using Redis 4.0.10 for caching installed in Linux.
Which version of Redis supports Python 3.1 or higher?
We tried searching the redis docs but couldn’t get the needed info. Thanks in advance.
Update:
In Linux server when we type redis-server —version it gives as redis server 4.0.10 and python 2.7.5. So we are planning to upgrade python then which redis server version (above 4.0.10) will support python 3.1 or higher

"Python 3.1" 3.1? Really?

Please see this table.
| Library version | Supported redis versions  |
|-----------------|---------------------------|
| 3.5.3           | <= 6.2 Family of releases |
| >= 4.5.0        | Version 5.0 to 7.0        |
| >= 5.0.0        | Version 5.0 to current    |

However, upgrading both the Redis Server and the client library is recommended.
https://github.com/redis/redis-py?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-redis-versions

Thank you for the info. We aren’t using redis-py. I have updated the question with more info and we need to know the redis server version that would support python 3.1 or higher

Redis Server does not depend on Python. Your application, if written in Python, depends on the Redis client library for Python, redis-py, in this case.
